# Отлов исключения в Kotlin при "цепной" обработке коллекции

Tags: исключения, коллекции, kotlin

Собственно такой парсер принятого json

```
val volunteers = SortedHashMap<Volunteer>()
        (0..json.length() - 1)
                .map { Volunteer(json.getJSONObject(it)) }
                .forEach { volunteers.put(it.id, it) }
        return volunteers
```

Печаль в том, что вот тут `.map { Volunteer(json.getJSONObject(it)) }` может возникнуть исключение.

Собственно вопрос в том, как грамотно обработать это исключение? В моем случае надо просто забить на ошибочную запись и продолжить разбор дальше. Можно сделать такое силами самих методов коллекции без разворачивания в цикл с `try` `catch`?

Comment: судя по всему нет, но try...catch можно использовать только внутри `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разворачивать в `try-catch` где-то, да придется. Напишите свою функцию, которая маппит элемент, а в процессе маппинга игнорирует исключение и возвращает `null` если оно выкинулось. И кидайте эту функцию в качестве лямбды для `map`.

**UPD от автора вопроса**

```
val volunteers = SortedHashMap<Volunteer>()
(0..json.length() - 1)
        .map {
            try {
                Volunteer(json.getJSONObject(it))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }
        .filterNotNull()
        .forEach { volunteers.put(it.id, it) }
```

Comment: я то, собственно, надеялся на что-то типа штатного `onErrorResumeNext` из мира Rx

Comment: Ну так то мир Rx, он тоже не безгрешен. А тут лишняя функция ничего не испортит.